# Calculate 'order effect'

Tags: spss, experiment-design, counterbalancing

My experiment has the following setup:

Participant completes exercise A.
Participant completes exercise B.

A counterbalancing design was used to remove (reduce?) the effect of order on the results; so half of the participants started with exercise B. I calculated significance scores using a paired-samples t-test in SPSS. However, I am also interested in analyzing whether or not the order of the exercises also influenced the results.

What would be the best way to answer this question? Does it even make sense - on a statistical level - to try this?

As was probably obvious from my explanation, my knowledge of statistics is (too) limited. If I explained something incorrectly or unclear, please let me know in the comments and I will try to provide you with some more valuable answer.

Comment: How to do this in SPSS does not seem central here, but for future reference please do read advice on software-related questions in the Help Center.

Comment: @NickCox Thank you for the advice - will keep an eye on that in the future. And yes, if anyone has advice on how to calculate this (not necessarily SPSS) I am still very interested to hear!

Comment: You might find a brief study of crossover studies to be helpful, if only to appreciate some of the issues involved (such as aliasing and carryover).  Some [notes from a Penn State course](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat509/node/123) have been extremely well written.